# Error using stackNavigator + tabBar - React Navigation4

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

After updating react-navigation to version 4. I can't run the project. Using the navigations. Displays this error. Sometimes the app goes all white. 
The complete project is available on git hub: https://github.com/brunowbbs/React_Navigation4

```
//Stack
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Screen1 from './Screen1';

const telas = createStackNavigator({
  Tela1:{
    screen:Screen1
  }
})

export default telas(telas);


//Tab

 import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
 import {createBottomTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';

import Tela1 from './Tab1';
import Tela2 from './Tab2';


const telas = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Tela1:{
    screen:Tela1
  },
  Tela2:{
    screen:Tela2
  }
})

export default createAppContainer(telas);
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xvxz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Fix replacing:

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
const telas = createStackNavigator({
  Tela1:{
    screen: Screen1,
  },
});
export default  telas(telas);
```

by

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import Screen1 from './Screen1';
const telas = createStackNavigator({
  Tela1:{
    screen: Screen1,
  },
});
export default  createAppContainer(telas);//<-- create container for navs
```

Comment: It worked! In the app there is the warning of componentWillMount deprecated. But I am not using this method.